# Why is this Javascript redirect code not working in internet explorer 8?

Tags: php, javascript

I am using this Javascript to redirect users. It works on FireFox and Chrome, but not in IE8.

```
window.location ="/public/index/offer?act=search";
```

Please Help.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add Linux Tag

Comment: Seconded, why Linux? (Why Zend Framework, for that matter?) Those tags don't seem relevant to the question.

That said, Jason, many of us still need to support IE 8 whether we like it or not. Most of the time, you don't get to choose your users' browsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
window.location.href = "/public/index/offer?act=search";
```